# intellij configuration with websphere liberty

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere-liberty

i have problem with websphere liberty app server.
i using intellij 12.1.4 and liberty 8.5.5.0
after creating my server in liberty and introducing liberty to intellij, in configuring at the bottom of form a warning with

```
   "warning: Server jvm arguements must contain -Xshareclasses:none"
```

displayed.

1- what is this warn? is it a problem? if yes can i fix it and how?
however i can run and debug my app with no problem.
2- if debugging app break points not hit where it should? i dont no why? tomcat has not this problem???
3- if run app in debug mode and stopping it, after stop, a message with this message will be appeared:

```
Error running WebSphere 8.5.5.0:
Unable to open debugger port: java.net.SocketException "socket close"
```

Thanks for your response.

Comment: @M.A.Kishawy Please stop simply adding the [tag:ibm] tag, this doesn't help in any way, it's just superflous

Comment: @msrd0 You have to add a comment to some of Kishawy posts to make him receive the comment. But I fully support you adding that tag is not useful in any way.

Comment: @Gas Since he edited the question (look in the revisions history), I can ping him here

Comment: @msrd0 I think your point of view is valid..maybe we can discuss this in other place because these comments are not related to this question...and I think it's better if we delete these comments after we are done here. Isn't there a chat room thingy in stackoverflow, I thought I saw some ppl using that :)

Comment: @Gas and msrd0 We can chat here
http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63521/ibm-tag
So if you like go ahead and delete your comments from this question if you like. Thanks